# MySQL- JOIN that groups in 1 record the min of a column and the max of another

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have a table of Members (member_id, name, etc..) and a table of Membership (id, member_id, membership starting date, membership expiration date) with a relation of one to many, because every year there is a new entry in Membership, per every member.

When I do :

```
SELECT * FROM members
INNER JOIN membership ON members.member_id = membership.member_id
```

I obtain multiple records for every member. How can I group records in only one record per member, that contains the MIN of membership starting date and the MAX of membership expiration date?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do your aggregation from a derived table of `membership`. For example:

```
SELECT m.*, ms.start_date, ms.exp_date
FROM members m
JOIN (SELECT member_id, MIN(start_date) AS start_date, MAX(exp_date) AS exp_date
      FROM membership
      GROUP BY member_id) ms ON ms.member_id = m.member_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use aggregation:

```
SELECT m.*, min(ms.start_date), max(ms.expiration_date)
FROM members m
     membership ms
     ON m.member_id = ms.member_id
GROUP BY m.member_id;
```

Comment: there are some errors in your code no ms join is missing

Comment: @Lorecn1 . . . What errors?  Except for a typo on the "start_date" it looks correct.